# convert columns date and datetime format from string format to datetime

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have one file. i am moving this file from blob storage to Sql table using copy activity.
Here I have 2 columns one date and another one is date time format. in source file those 2 columns are in string format. but sink those are in datetime format. it is throwing error as it is not valid datetime format.

> 1|SHOPS|2023-02-20||2023-02-20-12.07.12.861826|N|Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string format `2023-02-20-12.07.12.861826` is the reason for this error.

[image]

The above format is not supported in SQL and thats why it gave the invalid DateTime error.

You need to modify it to a valid date time format. Use dataflow for it and store the modified data in the same file. After dataflow, use copy activity to achieve your requirement.

In the dataflow, give your file as source and use the below expression for the particular column in the **derivedColumn** transformation.

```
concat(substring(date2,1,10),' ',replace(substring(split(date2,'-')[4],1,6),'.',':'),substring(split(date2,'-')[4],7))
```

[image]

In the sink, give the same dataset and set the **Output to single file** with **same filename** in the **sink settings**.

After dataflow activty, use copy activity with same source and sink datasets and debug the pipeline now.

[image]

The dataflow will modify your format and stores the data in the same file and copy activity will copy it to the target table.

[image]

**NOTE:** I had observed some milli seconds data loss for the `datetime` datatype of the sink table. To avoid it, I changed it to `datetime2` datatype and now its working without any data loss.

Comment: we have another column with only date, that is in correct format. but it is also throwing same error.

Comment: Can you provide the error image of this column?

Comment: ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value '2023-02-20' for column name 'Prop_25' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'DateTime' (precision:, scale:). Additional info: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: First, I also got the same error for the normal column. Later when I ran after publishing and re-importing the schema of the datasets and re-importing the mapping in copy activity, it got resolved. Try to do that and let me know if it still persists.

Comment: still facing same issue

Comment: Can you provide your copy activity mapping image? and also the schema image from the source dataset?

Comment: @ Rakesh Govindula
it is working, Thank you